# Why is my params hash nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, rails-console, pry

In my rails controller, in a pry session, my `params` hash is `nil`. `request.params` has the expected hash.

If I comment out the `params = …` line, `params` returns to normal.

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def update
    binding.pry
    params = params.require(:user).allow(:foo)
  end
end
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 8):

To begin with, `params` is a method.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html#method-i-params

In your code, when you write

```
params = params.require(:user).allow(:foo)
```

you initialize a variable called params.

When you hit your pry, you have already initialized (gets initialized upon loading of code) but not yet set the value of your variable, `params`.  Therefore, when you call it within your pry, it is set to `nil`. The method `params` is overwritten by your variable within the scope of your `update` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `params` hash is what you get when the user request the page. For example:

```
https://www.example.com/index.html?username=john&email=john@example.com
```

The `params` hash would be

```
{username: 'john', email: 'john@example.com'}
```

And you can assess then like `params[:username]`.

Looks like you are trying to use strong parameters to set what the user can or cannot update. In that case, what you should do is

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:foo))
end
```

This will only allow the user to update the `foo` attribute and nothing else.

Because this is so common, it is standard to write a private method called `user_params` and just call that method when you call `save`.

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update_attributes(user_params)
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:foo)
  end
```